# Grouping by multiple columns in EFCore results in InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Say we have models A, B and C. A has a many-to-many relationship with B and with C. I want to create following aggregation:

```
+--------+----------------+--------------+---------+
|  a_id  |  b_value_sum   | c_value_sum  | c_count |
+--------+----------------+--------------+---------+
| 1      |  20            | 10           | 40      | 
+--------+----------------+--------------+---------+
```

Query:

```
var query = 
    from a in context.A
    from b in a.B.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from c in b.C.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group new { b, c } by new { a.Id } into g
    select new
    {
        Id = g.Key.ToString(),
        ValueBSum = g.Sum(y => y.b.Value),
        ValueCSum = g.Sum(y => y.c.Value),
        ValueCCount = g.Count()
    };
```

Generated query:

```
SELECT 
    [c].[Id], 
    COALESCE(SUM([t].[Value]), 0.0), 
    COALESCE(SUM([t0].[Value]), 0.0), 
    COUNT(*)
FROM [A] AS [c]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        [b].[Value], 
        [c1].[A_Id]
    FROM [AB] AS [c1]
    INNER JOIN [B] AS [b] ON [c1].[B_Id] = [b].[Id]
) AS [t] ON [c].[Id] = [t].[A_Id]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        [s0].[Value], 
        [s].[A_Id]
    FROM [AC] AS [s]
    INNER JOIN [C] AS [s0] ON [s].[C_Id] = [s0].[Id]
) AS [t0] ON [c].[Id] = [t0].[A_Id]
GROUP BY [c].[Id]
```

Results in

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
```

One thing to notice is, that the outer select is missing the AS statements. E.g. AS BValueSum.

Replacing `new { a.Id }` with `a.id` resolves the issue. However I want to group by multiple columns, which always gives me the above error.

Stacktrace:

```
fail: UseCase[0]
       MyProject Request: Unhandled Exception for Request UseCase
      System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
         at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionExtensions.GetConstantValue[T](Expression expression)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.GetProjectionIndex(ProjectionBindingExpression projectionBindingExpression)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
         at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.ProcessShaper(Expression shaperExpression, RelationalCommandCache& relationalCommandCache, LambdaExpression& relatedDataLoaders, Int32& collectionId)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitShapedQuery(ShapedQueryExpression shapedQueryExpression)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.CountAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at MyProject.Shared.Models.PaginatedList`1.CreateAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Int32 pageNumber, Int32 pageSize) in MyProject\Shared\Models\PaginatedList.cs:line 0
         at MyProject.Shared.Behaviours.ValidationBehaviour`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next) in MyProject\Shared\Behaviours\ValidationBehaviour.cs:line 35
         at MyProject.Shared.Behaviours.UnhandledExceptionBehaviour`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next) in MyProject\Shared\Behaviours\UnhandledExceptionBehaviour.cs:line 18
```

Comment: Please add call stack.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?  Error messages are better in SQL Server Management Studio so I would try the query in SSMS.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv added stacktrace.

Comment: Which EF Core version? What happen if you remove `ToString()`?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv EFCore 6.0.2. Using ToString solves the issue. Make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably EF Core could not create projection for `.ToString()` from anonymous object.

Try to remove `.ToString()` and, if it is needed, post process records after materialization on the client side.